# Linux Remove files from command line that aren't files?

Tags: linux

I'm a complete beginner and I'm ssh connected to my school lab. At the beginning when I entered `ls` I got

- bin
- mail
- Mail

I moved on to a different section of the lab and now when I enter `ls` I get

- eagle.cs.umanitoba.ca 48% ls
- bin
- hip Skills
- mail
- Mail

staff members regarding machine up-keep and cleaning tasks so that the new staff would be successful in the workplace.

which is part of my resume which I had open in a different tab. I don't understand how it got there but I can't seem to remove it. I've tried `ls /hip, ls /hip Skills, ls /hip_Skills, rm /hip , rm /hip_Skills`. But *I always get that there is no such file or directory*. I know this is probably solved but I know so little about the subject I don't really know what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should type `rm -r hip/`, `ls hip/` when directory

or `ls :absolute_path_name`, `rm -r :absolute_directory_path_name`, `rm :absolute_path_name`

maybe you want to delete "hip Skills" directory you should type `rm -r hip\ Skiils/`

also putty program have auto complete function (tab)